# FHT doesn't work with the example code

Tags: audio

I'm trying to use the FHT librairy from (http://wiki.openmusiclabs.com/wiki/ArduinoFHT). I used the example code provided on the link, which is the following :

```
#include <FHT.h> // include the library

#define LIN_OUT8  1
#define FFT_N     64

void setup() 
{
  /*Turn off timer0 for lower jitter - 
    delay() and millis() killed*/
  TIMSK0 = 0;
  /*set the adc to free running mode*/
  ADCSRA = 0xe5;
  /*use adc0*/
  ADMUX = 0x40;
  /*turn off the digital input for adc0*/
  DIDR0 = 0x01;


  Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() 
{
  while(1) 
  { // reduces jitter
    cli();  // UDRE interrupt slows this way down on arduino1.0
    for (int i = 0 ; i < FHT_N ; i++) 
    { // save 256 samples
      while(!(ADCSRA & 0x10)); // wait for adc to be ready
      ADCSRA = 0xf5; // restart adc
      byte m = ADCL; // fetch adc data
      byte j = ADCH;
      int k = (j << 8) | m; // form into an int
      k -= 0x0200; // form into a signed int
      k <<= 6; // form into a 16b signed int
      fht_input[i] = k; // put real data into even bins
    }
    fht_window(); // window the data for better frequency response
    fht_reorder(); // reorder the data before doing the fft
    fht_run(); // process the data in the fft
    fht_mag_lin8(); // take the output of the fft
    sei();
    Serial.write(255);
    fht_lin_ou8[0];
    Serial.write(fht_lin_out8, FHT_N/2);
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:
`fht_lin_ou8' was not declared in this scope`

I canot resolve this probleme, ans help would be appreciate

Comment: There's three versions of the library on that site. I can't find that code you post in any of them.

Comment: Even the "program example" link is something different.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try to replace :

> fht_lin_ou8[0];

with :

fht_lin_out8[0];